# What file format will let me search for strings in the file extremely quickly?

Tags: python, file, search, full-text-search, hard-drive

I have a 100GB file of random strings of text between 4 and 200 characters long, one on each line.

I want to be able to find either a string within any string in the file e.g. any occurrence of "test" in "footestbar", if that's possible.

Otherwise I'd be happy being able to find lines/records that start with with a substring e.g. "foo" finds "footestbar" but not "testbarfoo".

I was thinking of sorting the file once and then recording the positions where lines with "a" start, where lines with "b" start, etc. This would let me quickly jump to the right section and reduce the time it takes. I could improve further by recording the positions where all three character combinations start to make it even faster, but something tells me there's a better way.

Comment: Searching 100GB of content in file. Really? If it is one time, it is fine. If you want it in real-time, I think you should check for text based search engines. for example ElasticSearch, Apache Lucene

Comment: I don't really like the idea of recording start of specific letters in sorted file. If you have your file sorted alphabetically by line, you can do binary search in just log n.

Comment: assuming you have a 100GB file, with everage line of 100 chars, keeping these indexes would result in about `3GB` (for keys and integer offsets)

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at this now: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247508/binary-search-in-a-sorted-text-file

Comment: @UrielEli 3G would fit in memory nicely, is it a good solution though? I could store that in some kind of simple database format like a Berkeley DB

Comment: i would not suggest that way, since it will consume much time even to produce it (unless you'e talking supercomputer terms, which is not bizarre as you have 100gb file). but if the lines have some repeating elements, you might want to keep every line as a key, what would be a little more expensive but faster. calculate the frequencies

Comment: http://sgrep.sourceforge.net/ looks like a useful tool

Comment: if you are searching for a word in a sorted file the best you can do is binary search which is `log(n)` ... otherwise you will need to use some tool like the ones mentioned (or write your own... you can look at the source code for many of them)

Comment: I could pre-process the file more than just sorting it though. I could create an index...

Answer (score 1):

I think a good start could be to generate a [DAFSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton?wprov=sfla1). You probably will have to combine it with a graph file format.